# Javamail read messages but ignore specific messages by id

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using javamail to read my inbox, but i have in my db a list of messagesId that i don't want to bring next time a read the inbox.
I see that java mail has the notTerm but i need to ignore a list of messageId, in this case i can't find how to do it.

This is my actual code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", provider);

props.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable","true");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
//props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

if (!port.equals("")) props.setProperty("mail." + provider + ".port", CONEXAO_EMAIL_PORTA);

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore();
store.connect(server, inbox, pass);

Folder inbox = store.getFolder(folder);
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(); //Here is where i need to change.
```

This code is working ok, but i need to change the inbox.getMessages() to some searchTerm and/or notTerm to ignore some specific messages.

Let me know if i was not clear.

Thanks!

Comment: So did you try to "change the inbox.getMessages() to some searchTerm and/or notTerm"?

Comment: Yes i did, i was trying to do SearchTerm st = new notTerm(new MessageIDTerm(messageId)); but this way i can pass just one message id, i need to pass a list.

Comment: Did you try combining the terms with `AndTerm`?

Comment: No, i cannot quite understand how...i basically need to use more than one notTerm...i didnt know i can combine with the AndTerm...

Comment: @pingw33n thanks i think i got it work, just another thing, i cant find a SearchTerm for limit the number of messages i whant to get, for example, the inbox has 200 messages but i just want 20...do you have any tip so i can find the solution?

Comment: There's no direct way to do that. But you can try narrowing the search using the message date for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54796/discussion-between-pecci-and-pingw33n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude multiple message IDs you can do something like this:

```
SearchTerm st = new NotTerm(new OrTerm(new StringTerm[]{ 
    new MessageIDTerm(messageId1),
    new MessageIDTerm(messageId2),
    ... })
```

Unfortunately there's no direct way to limit the number of messages returned. But you can partially workaround this by narrowing the search using `ReceivedDateTerm` and performing multiple searches until you get the needed amount of messages.

Comment: You want OrTerm, not AndTerm.  Remember also that an IMAP search doesn't return the messages, it returns the message numbers, so it's pretty cheap to get back a long list of message numbers and just ignore the ones you don't want to look at right now.